# Adjust EPS icons to same size and weight?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, icon, resize, eps

I have a pack of icons in .eps format, but some of them appear to be different in the size (guess have different purposes for website). Also, when I try to resize them in Illustrator, the weight of the shapes didn't match.

I need to create some more icons and add as a source to a Presentation slide.

So I have two problems:

1. How to adjust the EPS icons to match the same weight/scale/appearance at the same size?
2. How to create more icons in the same weight at the same size?

Thanks if anyone can support me with your thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu of the transform panel, make sure "Scale Strokes and Effects" is unchecked. You should then be able to scale objects without their strokeweights getting changed. As for creating new icons in the style of the ones you already have - just look at the stroke weights and use those values for the new icons.

[image: transform menu]

Comment: I assume the OP is dealing with icons converted to shapes, as in 'outlined strokes'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for an automatic way, one-click solution to make strokes in icons from different sources equally thick, that's not going to happen.

I've found myself in the same situation more than once, and pretty much ended up redrawing every single icon from scratch, just to make sure they are done in outlines (not fills), which makes it easier to adjust thickness and color consistently.